# Missing branch name with zsh git prompt on MacOS Catalina

Tags: git, zsh, macos-catalina, zshrc, zsh-completion

My `.zshrc` looks like this:

```
source /Users/crmpicco/zsh-git-prompt/zshrc.sh
PROMPT="%B%n@MBP%~%b$(git_super_status) %# "
```

My prompt looks like this:

`crmpicco@MBP/var/www/belleisle/symfony(:|✔) %`

if I open a new tab in the Terminal the git branch is shown and looks like this (the branch name is "symfony-3-4-30":

`crmpicco@MBP/var/www/belleisle/symfony(symfony-3-4-30|✔) %`

I'm not sure what has gone wrong, perhaps a MacOS upgrade has knocked this out because it was working well for months.

Comment: Do you expect the former (with `:`) to be like the latter?

Comment: @Adam Yes, I expect the git branch name to display. It seems strange to me it doesn't open in my first tab but does in subsequent tabs.

Comment: I expect when the prompt is resolved during shell initialisation the current directory isn't set properly.

Comment: @Adam An issue with Zsh?

Comment: Does your `.zshrc` automatically `cd` you into `/var/www/belleisle/symfony`?

Comment: @Adam No, I don't think so - but it's not my code. This is the contents of the file. https://gist.github.com/crmpicco/9c4b50d9bcc6112870a33084b9c43ea1

Comment: The command substitution is being evaluated when you define `PROMPT`, not when you display the prompt. Your subsequent tabs are probably being opened with a different working directory (the Git repository), and your `.zshrc` file is defining `PROMPT` anew for each tab.